# Bonjour communication wrapper for Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, bonjour

I've been using MYNetwork by the venerable Jens Alfke for an app of mine that allows devices to connect and share info over the network, it's actually a mission-critical part of the app. I tried writing my own wrapper for all of the C-level stuff you have to do for Bonjour, but it didn't work out so well, so I moved to MYNetwork.

It's been great so far, but the fact it's essentially opaque to me is causing trouble, as is that I want to move over to ARC once we can submit apps with it (there's a lot of Objective-C object references in structs, which ARC *hates*).

Can anyone recommend a similar wrapper, ideally that allows easy message passing between a client and a server over Bonjour as well as service discovery?

Comment: Are you are of the `NSNetService` family of classes?

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought- Would using ZeroMQ advertised and discovered by the stock NSNetService suffice? Separating the service pub/sub from the actual communication would allow you to use other bonjour libraries like Avahi on linux too. ZeroMQ is sufficiently simple to make wrapping trivial, yet powerful enough to cope with complex network topologies, fast.

I have experience with both technologies in isolation but not together although I see no reason why it wouldn't work. The only caveat right now is the limited body of collective experience of ZeroMQ use on iOS but I'd expect that to change over time.

Answer (score 1):

You know you can disable ARC for specific files?  So, you can just disable ARC for the library, and keep it on for your other files.

[Disable Automatic Reference Counting for Some Files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6448874/456851)