# dealloc method does not exist by default in ios5 based projects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I noticed that there is no dealloc method already placed in various class files when i create an ios5 based project, but I remember that there is a ready-made dealloc method placed in most of these files in ios 4.3 based projects ...
does that mean that if I did not release allocated objects, no memory leak will happen ? or should I my own dealloc method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS 5 contains feature called ARC, Automatic Reference Counting, http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios5/
which means that developer is no longer responsible for manual memory management.

Answer (score 3):

Only if you use ARC. I guess this change is an intensive for us to do so. If you don't you should implement the dealloc as you did before.

Comment: is there an option in XCode to enable ARC for the project ? or it needs coding ?

Comment: I don't see why you would want to go without ARC, is there a reason to avoid using it?

Comment: @JaHelia you need to refactor your code to be ARC compliant (Edit->Refactor->Convert To Objective-C ARC), more info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448874/automatic-reference-counting-for-some-files.

Answer (score 1):

This is because iOS 5 projects,by default have [ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385212/how-does-the-new-automatic-reference-counting-mechanism-work) enabled. On an ARC enabled projects, all releases, autoreleases and deallocs are illegal.

Comment: I have not started development on iOS 5 yet, will the compiler throw a warning? Build will fail? If you have releases?

Comment: With new projects ARC will already be enabled. For old projects which have manual memory management, you can upgrade to use ARC or just opt out from ARC. See this:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226