# iPhone ARC & Facebook SDK

Tags: iphone, facebook, automatic-ref-counting

I'm getting all kinds of build errors with Facebook's SDK because my app uses ARC. I try to remove the Facebook files from the compiler to avoid this, but I get an Apple Mach-O error when I remove the Facebook.m file. If I put that back in the compile sources, I get the ARC errors.

Anyone run into this?

Comment: How did you overcome this issue ? i tried adding -fno-objc-arc but i still end up having an error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701780/using-non-arc-code-in-an-arc-enabled-project-adding-facebook

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you exclude them from arc with Compiler flag 
      -fno-objc-arc
? 
You can see a Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448874/automatic-reference-counting-for-some-files)

Answer (score 5):

And this is why distributing a shared library by copy and pasting files is **bad**. A library should be distributed as it's own Xcode projects with a static library target, so that the build setting requirements of your projects and the libraries you use can not screw up one or the other.

File a bug for the Facebook SDK here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues

And in the mean time add the `-fno-objc-arc` flag to the implementation files in the Facebook SDK. You can do this by;

1. Select your application target
2. Go to the *Build Phases* tab
3. Add for each file under the *Compile Sources* section.

Comment: that's a lot of for-eaching. if you select multiple files and hit enter you can set -fno-objc-arc on all of them at once.

Answer (score 2):

The new SDK does not explicitly support ARC out of the box, but there is a shell scrip to build a static library that can be used within your ARC project. Just navigate to your local git repo and run

```
% ~/facebook-ios-sdk/scripts/build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh
```

This will create the static library under the /lib/facebook-ios-sdk folder (e.g. ~/facebook-ios-sdk/lib/facebook-ios-sdk). You may then drag the facebook-ios-sdk folder into the app Xcode project to include the iOS Facebook SDK static library.

Comment: Supporting ARC is described on Facebook's own SDK page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

Answer (score 0):

there are actually very few changes needed to make the Facebook iOS sdk compatible with ARC. I have made the changes in my code , but , I do not know who to send it back to the community, any pointers ?

here is a post I made to explain how to use it with ARC the simple way on Xcode 4.2:
http://nabtech.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/facebook-ios-sdk-and-arc/

Comment: Will it be possible for you to email me your version of the Facebook iOS sdk, i am stuck with a similar issue for days. jamespresely@gmail.com

Comment: I actually found another way which I posted here. when including the sdk , include it with the project file but do not check add to target. then on you project add the sdk as static library.that way you can compile the sdk without ARC but your code with no problem.