# Trouble integrating Facebook into iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad, ios5

I've been following this [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/) on integrating Facebook into my app. Everything is going well except for when I add in the Facebook SDK to my project.

I have added in all the code to enable SSO, however when I build and run my project I get loads of errors caused by the [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk):

[image]

I think it may be due to the sdk being out of date but I got it from the git page so I would have thought it should be compatible with iOS 5.

Maybe I need to carry out some extra steps when adding it into my project? All I did was literally drag and drop the src folder in (not the .pch and .xcodeproj files).

Please can someone help me out - I've tried searching for help online but couldn't find anything of use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone ARC & Facebook SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421338/iphone-arc-facebook-sdk)

Comment: See also [Using Non-ARC Code in an ARC-Enabled Project - Adding Facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701780/using-non-arc-code-in-an-arc-enabled-project-adding-facebook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDK is outdated for the ARC yes. You have to turn off ARC for the SDK, check this answer out: [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

Answer (score 1):

go to project navigator->Build Settings

set Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting to NO.