# How to resolve Duplicate symbol between 2 libraries?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, class

Here is error logs between libfacebook_ios_sdk.a and libMMSDK.a

```
Duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SBJsonParser in /Users/RAGOpoR/Desktop
/Objective C/Archive Project/my Project/SVN/iOS temp/iPORTALs/code/Classes
/facebook-ios-sdk/libfacebook_ios_sdk.a(SBJsonParser.o) and     
/Users/RAGOpoR/Desktop/Objective C/Archive Project/my Project/SVN/iOS temp
/iPORTALs/code/Classes/MMAdView/libMMSDK.a(SBJsonParser.o) for architecture armv7
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the libraries are compiled with your project, you can simply remove the SBJson files from the Facebook SDK (or MMSDK, but I've done this successfully with Facebook before), clean and rebuild the dependency.

Keep in mind that Facebook SDK ships with an old version of SBJson and you may have to tweak some of the method calls it uses if MMSDK ships with a newer one.

Comment: According to Facebook have release ARC version, it include file into libfacebook_ios_sdk.a that why i can't delete it!.

Comment: Where did you get the facebook ARC version? I'm sure they have the source as well.

Comment: Facebook SDK release 2 version, the source code that not yet support Arc. So you advise me to use The code not support ARC and then convert to ARC right ?

Comment: No, just tell the compiler to not use ARC for those facebook files with -fno-objc-arc. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421338/iphone-arc-facebook-sdk)

Comment: @RAGOpoR You clearly don't understand what ARC is. Disabling it just means that the library manages its own retain counts, which it's designed to do and isn't related to performance.

Comment: remove SBJsonParser from facebook SDK still meet the problem, because the compiler can't find SBJsonParser.h in libMMSDK.a

Comment: Apple engineer said in WWDC 2011"ARC retain and release are 30% faster than Manual retain/release"

Answer (score 0):

Try to update [MillenialMedia SDK](http://mmedia.com/resources/sdk-api/). The latest for today is 5.4.1 which consist of two frameworks - `SpeechKit.framework` and `MillenialMeda.framework`.

Updating of MMSDK is very simple - just remove all previous files from your project. Clean your Library Search Path and Framework Search Path (any MMSDK or MellinalMedia paths). [Also see installation manual.](http://docs.millennialmedia.com/iOS-SDK/)
[image]

Then copy new frameworks from fresh downloaded SDK package to the Project's top level folder.
[image: Copy frameworks here]

Then add this frameworks to your Target's -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries
[image]

Change import style from `#import "MMSDK.h"` to `#import <MillennialMedia/MMSDK.h>`

Also don't forget to add `EventKit.framework`, if you not added it yet and check other required frameworks:

- AdSupport.framework
- AudioToolbox.framework
- AVFoundation.framework
- CFNetwork.framework
- CoreGraphics.framework
- CoreLocation.framework
- EventKit.framework
- Foundation.framework
- MediaPlayer.framework
- MobileCoreServices.framework
- PassKit.framework
- QuartzCore.framework
- Security.framework
- Social.framework
- SpeechKit.framework (included in the SDK download)
- StoreKit.framework
- SystemConfiguration.framework
- UIKit.framework