# Facebook API not working perfectly for IOS5

Tags: iphone, facebook, automatic-ref-counting

I ve Downloaded Facebook API fro IOS 5....But its showing some errors regrading the memory release...Since apple has introduced autorelease in IOS 5....

I referred [this](http://sugartin.info/2011/08/10/ios5-how-to-turn-off-arc-on-individual-files/)  and tried blocking ARC for certain files ,bt it doesn't work for me... 
Is there any other methods to stop ARC in IOS 5?
How to overcome this?

Any one plz provide me the link for downloading the Facebook API for IOS 5...

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone ARC & Facebook SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421338/iphone-arc-facebook-sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [official SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk), you should compile it as a static library, not with your code, and then link your app with that library. You could see how it is done in SDK examples, and also [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#sdk) is some information about building process. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link with working Source Code:

```
 http://www.apress.com/9781430235422
```

Download complete source code from "Source Code/Downloads"

Comment: Dude I'm asking api for iOS 5 urs work fine till iOS 4 series bt my pblm is ARC...