# Using code that doesn't support ARC, from an ARC project

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

I want to use some code (a folder full of files, basically) but it is written pre ARC.

I want to use this from a project written in ARC so I can't just drop the code into my project (I think).

I'm wondering if there's a way to solve this by creating a framework or static library from the non-ARC files that I can reference in my ARC project.

Can this work? Any ideas as to the best route to follow?

Comment: Please take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448874/disable-automatic-reference-counting-for-some-files and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project

Comment: Useful, per file is kind of nasty though. Any way to create a project that is non-ARC that can be referenced from an ARC project.

Comment: If the project is compiled and added as a framework, you could accomplish that.