# I'm trying to implement GuiCocoa/Calendar into my project, which uses ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, calendar, automatic-ref-counting

Here's the GitHub link: https://github.com/guicocoa/calendar

I went through the source code and I'm trying to make it "ARC friendly" for use in my project, but I'm not very well versed in ARC (however, I do with to continue using it), so can someone help me out?

Or maybe an easier solution -- is there a linker I can put into my project where it'll just leave that "folder" alone and I can go on my merry way? :)

THanks
rnc505

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-fno-objc-arc` for the individual files.

See [Disable Automatic Reference Counting for Some Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448874/disable-automatic-reference-counting-for-some-files) and [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

I did this for some libraries that I was using and came back after months of using ARC and cleaned them up myself. You really don't want to do it before you understand ARC well, so your instinct is right on.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could go and convert the project to ARC. I forked it on GitHub and did it. I need a project like this so thought it'd be useful for me anyway. Here's my fork:

https://github.com/mattjgalloway/calendar