# iOS : MBProgressHUD and Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, ios5, mbprogresshud

In xCode 4.2 & iOS 5 SDK , Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) is introduced. However, it made many third party libraries failed to compile, e.g. MBProgressHUD.

Is there any way to avoid those compile errors (only for those 3rd party libraries)? Or should I disable ARC ?

Comment: Btw, MBProgressHUD has support for ARC now

Comment: Seems I am using an old version of MBProgressHUD...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable/disable on a per-file basis.

[Disable Automatic Reference Counting for Some Files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6448874/1224741)