# About MKStoreKit Error

Tags: xcode4.3, mkstorekit

My Xcode project imported MKStoreKit.
And I followed to this.
http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/using-mkstorekit-in-your-apps/
But it has many error.

SFHFKeychainUtils.m
,ARC Casting Rules
,Semantic issue
,ARC Restrictions

Total 39 bugs.

I linked StoreKit.framework,Security.framework.

-I write this Initialize code in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
Initialize code is [MKStoreManager sharedManager];

However Bugs appears.
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable ARC on all of the MKStoreKit files—including JSONKit, SFHFKeychainUtils, and NSData+Base64. Details are in this post

[Disable Automatic Reference Counting for Some Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448874/disable-automatic-reference-counting-for-some-files)

Then comment out all of the the error message lines

```
/*
#if ! __has_feature(objc_arc)
#error MKStoreKit is ARC only. Either turn on ARC for the project or use -fobjc-arc flag
#endif
*/
```

That gets rid of all but one error in this method. But he just forgot to declare it in the .h

```
+(id) receiptForKey:(NSString*) key {

  NSData *receipt = [MKStoreManager objectForKey:key];
  if(!receipt)
    receipt = [MKStoreManager objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-receipt", key]];

  return receipt;               
}
```

Add this line in your .h

```
+(id) objectForKey:(NSString*) key;
```

The code will now compile. Don't know if it works, but at least it compiles.