# Communicate with REST service from ios5 app

Tags: ios, xcode, rest

I'm building an application that needs to communicate with a REST service.
The application is using ARC so ASIHTTPRequest is NOT an option. 
Also RESTKit horribly failed when we tried to use it.

How should we tackle sending the http request? (preferably asynchronicly) and 'storing' the data to be parsed by an XML parser (I don't really need help with that, just need to know how to feed it the data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use ARC everywhere, check out this question and answer, you could just disable ARC for the third party libraries.

[Disable Automatic Reference Counting for Some Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448874/disable-automatic-reference-counting-for-some-files)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AFNetworking its a very good Lib for REST communication protocol. And you can just disable ARC for AFNetworking as well.