# Xcode facebook connect for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

Hope you can help me with this errors.

1. I've downloaded the SDK from GIT repository.
2. I've copied the /SRC/ in my Xcode 4.2 project.
3. I have this code on AppDelegate.h

   > ```
   > #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   > #import "FBConnect.h"
   >
   > @class ViewController;
   >
   > @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,FBSessionDelegate> {
   >     Facebook *facebook;
   > }
   >
   > @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
   > @property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
   > @property (nonatomic, retain) Facebook *facebook;
   >
   > @end
   > ```
4. I have this code on AppDelegate.m

   > ```
   > #import "AppDelegate.h"
   > #import "ViewController.h"
   >
   > @implementation AppDelegate
   >
   > @synthesize window = _window;
   > @synthesize viewController = _viewController;
   > @synthesize facebook;
   >
   >
   > - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
   > {
   >
   >     self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
   >     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   >
   >     facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"HERE_APP_ID" andDelegate:self];
   >
   >     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   >
   >     if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
   >         facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
   >         facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
   >     }
   >
   >     if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
   >         [facebook authorize:nil];
   >     }
   >
   >     return YES;
   > }
   >
   > - (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
   >     return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];
   > }
   >
   >
   > -(void) fbDidLogin {
   >     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   >     [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
   >     [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
   >     [defaults synchronize];
   >
   > }
   > ```
5. My .plist file configured with my fb"HERE_MY_APP_ID"
6. The structure of my project is

> - MyProject
>
>   - src
>   - AppDelegate.h
>   - AppDelegate.m
>   - MainStoryboard.storyboard
>   - ViewController.h
>   - ViewController.m
>   - Supporting Files
> - Frameworks
> - Products

The thing is that I don't have any errors, but when I Run I got a lot of them. Almost 81, and a warning. Hope you can help me. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Your project uses ARC, the facebook SDK doesn't. It's telling you the method `-release` isn't available. You need to look into disabling ARC processing on the FB SDK.

Comment: @Jessedc Might be better to post this as an answer. Otherwise people will waste time reading the question thinking no one has posted an answer only do realize you did in the comments!

Comment: @idz my concern with my above comment as an answer is that the OP may need a better description of what ARC is, how to disable it etc etc.

Comment: @Jessedc, yeah you could be right ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Automatic Reference Counting for Some Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448874/disable-automatic-reference-counting-for-some-files)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for answer this question :).  @Jessedc thank you so much!... Now it's working without any errors :-)

Comment: @RicardoGonzales I have added my comment as an answer, ha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see your project is using ARC and the facebook SDK is not. It's telling you the method `-release` isn't available so you need to look into disabling ARC for the Facebook SDK.