# How to create share intent for iOS like Android?

Tags: ios, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

I've tried building a share intent for my iOS application but only the message and email share buttons appear, I want it to show everything that can send the link like in android it shows everything from facebook, twitter, whatsapp, messenger etc.

Im using this code

```
NSString *textToShare = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.njoftime.io/%@",[[NjoftimeManager getSelectedListing] objectForKey:@"_id"]];
NSArray *itemsToShare = @[textToShare];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities: nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll]; //or whichever you don't need
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I've seen some questuons here and some say either you share directly to facebook or this way.

Any idea?

Comment: You need to login in those applications (facebook, twitter etc) to list it in `UIActivityViewController`

Comment: nope, im always logged in and it doesnt appear

Comment: Try login those applications from `Settings`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With iOS 8 you will have something similar to Android Intents. Use  [App Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html).

If you want to use in ios6 & ios7 then use  [sharekit.](http://getsharekit.com/)

I am not sure sharekit is working or not but you can give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com).

**Supported Services:**

Delicious,
Email,
Facebook,
Google Reader,
Instapaper,
Pinboard,
Read It Later,
Tumblr,
Twitter, and much more.

Comment: there is no other way except for external libraries ? cause this shareKit is with ARC

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448874/disable-automatic-reference-counting-for-some-files